# jqGrid multiselect gives only ids when top checkbox has been checked?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with multiselect:true. In a click event of a button I try to retrieve the ids like:

```
var ids = $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

However I only get ids to be filled with something if I select the top checkbox in the header. If I do not select that one in the header but select several checkboxes in the column ids has no selected ids in it. How to overcome this?

sellarrrow is according to this example written correctly: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, select Advanced, Multiselect example.

Comment: Did you notice that you misspelled `selarrow`?

Comment: I thought so too but when I tried it then nothing worked anymore. Besides I find it curious that the top checkbox still works even when misspelled.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: Actually, it is `selarrrow`. I guess it comes from "SELected ARRay ROWs": http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options&s[]=selarrrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a defaulting setup where this was set:

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) { return false; },
```

Setting that to true gave me back the power.

Answer (score 2):

HI add beforeSelectRow: cancelRowClickSelection,

property to jq grid. function defenition is given below. It is working perfectly.

```
function cancelRowClickSelection(rowid, e) 
{
 var target=e.originalTarget;
 var str=target.innerHTML;
 if(target.classList!=null && target.classList!="undefined" && target.classList[0]!=null && target.classList[0]!="undefined")
 {
  if(target.classList[0]=="cbox")
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 if(str.indexOf("input")!=-1 || str.indexOf("INPUT")!=-1)
 {
  return true;
 }
 return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using below code to retrieve randomly selected rows and its working fine ..

```
var selArr = $("#my_grid").getGridParam("selarrrow");
```

Answer (score 1):

if i put

```
$('#id ').getGridParam('selectarrow')
```

instead of

```
$('# ').JQgrid('getGridParam','selectarrow')
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of the solutions presented, without luck.
This is what I ended up with - just finding the data value...

complete standalone example ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqGrid4/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqGrid4/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqGrid4/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqGrid4/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="gridFIRST" action="A" method="post">
    <input id="gridFIRST_thinglist" name="gridFIRST[thinglist]" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="gridFIRST_X"  name="gridFIRST[do_X]" type="submit" value="Let Out 0">
</form>
<form id="gridSECOND" action="B" method="post">
    <input id="gridSECOND_thinglist"  name="gridSECOND[thinglist]" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="gridSECOND_Y" name="gridSECOND[do_Y]" type="submit" value="Bring In 0">
</form>
<table summary="grid" id="thisJqGrid"></table>
<div id="thisJqGridPager"></div>


<script>
function selectedThingsClass()
    {
    this.list = new Array();
    this.dpush = function(thing) { if(this.list.indexOf(thing) == -1) /* if unique */ this.list.push(thing); }
    this.dpop = function (thing) { var n = this.list.indexOf(thing); if(n >= 0) this.list.splice(n, 1); }
    this.getCount = function () { return 0+this.list.length; }
    this.thingSelected = function (isChecked,thing) { if(isChecked) this.dpush(thing); else this.dpop(thing); }
    }

function handleSelectedRow(thing) {
    var jqgcell     = jQuery('#thisJqGrid').getCell(thing, 0);
    var petName     = jQuery('#thisJqGrid').getCell(thing, 'COL2');
    var cbIsChecked = (jQuery(jqgcell).attr('checked') == 'checked') ? true : false;
    switch(petName)
        {
        case 'Dog':
            selectedThingsCat.thingSelected(cbIsChecked,thing);
            jQuery('#gridSECOND_thinglist').val(selectedThingsCat.list.toString());
            jQuery('#gridSECOND_Y').val("Bring In "+selectedThingsCat.getCount());
            break;
        case 'Cat':
            selectedThingsDog.thingSelected(cbIsChecked,thing);
            jQuery('#gridFIRST_thinglist').val(selectedThingsDog.list.toString());
            jQuery('#gridFIRST_X').val("Let Out "+selectedThingsDog.getCount());
            break;
        }
    }

var selectedThingsDog = new selectedThingsClass();
var selectedThingsCat = new selectedThingsClass();

function index_handleSelectedRow(rowIndex)
    {
    // convert row-index to JSON-Data ID
    var rowDataArr = jQuery("#thisJqGrid").getRowData();
    handleSelectedRow(rowDataArr[rowIndex].COL1);
    }

var mydata = [
    {id:"thing01",COL1:"thing01",COL2:"Dog"},
    {id:"thing02",COL1:"thing02",COL2:"Cat"},
    {id:"thing03",COL1:"thing03",COL2:"Cat"},
    {id:"thing04",COL1:"thing04",COL2:"Dog"},
    {id:"thing05",COL1:"thing05",COL2:"Cat"},
    {id:"thing06",COL1:"thing06",COL2:"Dog"},
    {id:"thing07",COL1:"thing07",COL2:"Cat"},
    {id:"thing08",COL1:"thing08",COL2:"Cat"},
    {id:"thing09",COL1:"thing09",COL2:"Dog"},
    {id:"thing10",COL1:"thing10",COL2:"Dog"}
    ];

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery("#thisJqGrid").jqGrid({
            onSelectAll: function(rowIdxArray, sts)
                { jQuery(rowIdxArray).each(function(rowIndex){ index_handleSelectedRow(rowIndex); } ); },
            onSelectRow: function(rowJsonId)
                { handleSelectedRow(rowJsonId); },
            multiselect: true,
            colNames:[ 'Thing','Pet' ],
            colModel: [ { name:'COL1', width:10 }, { name:'COL2', width:10 }, ],
            datatype: "local", data: mydata,
            width: "200", height: "100%",
            postData: { "oper":"grid" },
            toolbar: [true,"top"],
            rowNum:10,
            sortname: "COL1",
            sortorder: "asc",
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```